# Resize image and save in Document crash

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimage

in my app I need to create via code the image that will be used. I download a full screen version of image and then I create all the clippings I need. This approach reduce the MB the user will be download from the server.
The image downloaded are approximately 300. The size is 1024x768 on iPad non-retina and 2048x1536 on iPad retina.

This is the algorithm that I use to resize the image to create the clippings that I need. For each image is created another reduced version and then will be saved in Document folder.

I using ARC and GCD.

```
    CGFloat screenScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    
    NSString * imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:imageName ofType:nil];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    CGSize newImageSize = [image resizeImageSettingWidth:(380.0f * screenScale)];
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newImageSize.width,newImageSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    
    NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.9f);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    
    NSString * newImageName;
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] &&
        ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)) {
        
        newImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-article@2x.jpg", [imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
        
    }
    else {
        
        newImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-article.jpg", [imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
    }
    
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:newImageName]; 
    [jpegData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

After an unknown number of resizing the app crashes probably for a Memory Warning. The crash occurs only on iPad 4th generation, on iPad2 this work perfectly.
Maybe the problem is that autorelease object are release late and this produce an accumulate of memory ?

Comment: you can know very easily if it's a memory crash if you use instruments... in this case try to isolate the issue; allow more time between one resize/save and the next, etc... otherwise: on which line does it crash?

Comment: If I insert a delay between one resize/save and the next, the app crash !

Comment: how do you insert the delay?